# Test dates using date.today()?

Tags: python, date

```
def test_dates(self):
    days = (date.today() + timedelta(days=2)) - date.today()
    print days
    if days >= -2 and days <= 4:
        print days
```

How do I check that difference between two dates is in the range -2 to 4 days?

Answer (score 1):

`days` is a `datetime.timedelta` object.  You need the `days` field from that.

```
if days.days >+ -2 and days.days < 4:
```

Or more succinctly

```
if -2 <= days.days < 4:
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `days` is a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. Use `days.days` to get the integer number of days.

Answer (score 0):

using `days.days >= 2 and days.days <= 4` is ok

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
if days.days >= -2 and days.days <= 4:
print days
```

Comment: What does this add to previously posted answers?

Comment: Nothing, but when I wrote it the other answers were not there :D